# mongoDB injection

Tags: java, mongodb, code-injection

is there a common pattern in Java to avoid mongoDB injection attacks?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify your question with the language you intend to interface mongo with?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use one of the supported drivers. Don't deserialize strings as JSON and pass them as queries, e.g. dont' do this (in Ruby):

```
collection.send(query_type, JSON.parse(parameters))
```

where `query_type` and `parameters` are strings coming from a form. You would have to be criminally stupid to do this though.

Since there's no query language as such there's not the same room for injection. Part of the reason that SQL injection attacks are possible is that the action to take (`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc.) is part of the query string. MongoDB, and many other newer databases, don't work like that, instead the action is a part of the API. Where SQL drivers only have `query` and in some cases `exec`, MongoDB has `find`, `update`, `insert` and `remove`.

Answer (score 5):

You can build MongoDB querys with Javascript in the where clause and here injection can happen. Here explanation how to prevent this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection

Answer (score 1):

Most of the drivers are setup where you construct queries as the languages representation of BSON documents. What languages do you intend to use mongo in?

Answer (score 1):

yes there is, by using regex search.
Ex: lets say you do check by username and you are not using EQ op.
If i pass [a-z] for example i will bypass your login action :).

But anyway, it very much depends on the logic of how things are implemented in the solution.